# How to solve 500 Internal error in Laravel API

Tags: laravel

I'm creating an API in Laravel which allows Users to post their projects.

// This is my ProjectController

```
public function index(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {
        $query = Project::query();

        // apply filters
        if ($request->has('domain')) {
            $query->where('domain', $request->input('domain'));
        }
        if ($request->has('skills')) {
            $query->whereHas('skills', function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->whereIn('name', explode(',', $request->input('skills')));
            });
        }
        if ($request->has('hourly_rate')) {
            $query->where('hourly_rate', '<=', $request->input('hourly_rate'));
        }
        if ($request->has('date_posted')) {
            $query->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->input('date_posted'))->startOfDay());
        }

        // sort results
        if ($request->has('sort_by') && in_array($request->input('sort_by'), ['hourly_rate', 'created_at'])) {
            $sortOrder = $request->input('sort_order', 'desc');
            $query->orderBy($request->input('sort_by'), $sortOrder);
        }

        $projects = $query->paginate($request->input('per_page', 10));

        return response()->json($projects, 200);
    }
```

I have seeded the database with dummy projects, however when I visit `http://localhost:8000/api/projects` in POSTMAN I get a `500 Internal Server Error`.

// My API route file

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
//    Route::apiResource('users', UserController::class);

        Route::apiResource('projects', ProjectController::class);
        Route::apiResource('bids', BidController::class);
        Route::apiResource('messages', MessageController::class);
        Route::apiResource('reviews', ReviewController::class);
    });
    
    Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

Comment: Check the logs in your project under `storage/logs`

Comment: In the log I see 'Vite Manifest not Found'. I have done npm run dev, still same error.

Comment: @GillesAshley you "_have to_" run `npm run build`

Comment: I did and the error has now changed to `Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/app.scss.`

Comment: @GillesAshley check the `public` folder and verify if `hot` file is not there, or delete if its there. additionally, try running `npm run dev` and  check if you can access that project url without error

Comment: So now when I visit the same url `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/` I get 403 Forbidden Error.

Comment: So, you need to pass a Bearer token or whatever your authentication driver is

Comment: Yeah, that 403 would be from the sanctum middleware you're using: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum

Comment: @matiaslauriti, I passed in the Bearer-token as you said, and now it take takes me to the login. I logged in several times and the login authenticates perfectly, but  `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/` still takes me to the login screen.

Comment: @KnapsackInjury I have authenticated, but my routes are still redirecting to the login route.

Comment: I commented the sanctum middleware and now the projects route works. Like so `//Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('projects', ProjectController::class);
    Route::apiResource('bids', BidController::class);
    Route::apiResource('messages', MessageController::class);
    Route::apiResource('reviews', ReviewController::class);
//});`